# Recording PCM on Windows Phone 8 using AudioVideoCaptureDevice

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

The following code correctly records audio recorded from my Windows Phone 8 device to isolated storage using the AMR and AAC formats. However, when I try to record the PCM format the app crashes with the error:

```
    Value does not fall within the expected range.
Windows.Phone.Media.Capture.AudioVideoCaptureDevice.StartRecordingToStreamAsync(IRandomAccessStream stream)
       at WP8.Classes.AudioCaptureController.<StartRecordingAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
       at WP8.ViewModels.CameraPageViewModel.<capture>d__13.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
       at WP8.ViewModels.CameraPageViewModel.<TakePictureAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<ThrowAsync>b__0(Object state)
```

The code I have working is as follows:

```
private AudioVideoCaptureDevice mic;
    private IRandomAccessStream sst;
    private string path;

    public async Task MicStartAsync()
    {
      mic = await AudioVideoCaptureDevice.OpenForAudioOnlyAsync();
      mic.AudioEncodingFormat = CameraCaptureAudioFormat.Pcm;
    }

    public async Task StartRecordingAsync()
    {
      IsolatedStorageAccess iso = new IsolatedStorageAccess();
      sst = await iso.SetUpFileStreamForSavingAudioAsync("123.pcm");
      await mic.StartRecordingToStreamAsync(sst);
      path = iso.Path;
    }

    public async Task StopRecordingAsync()
    {
      await mic.StopRecordingAsync();
      sst.AsStream().Dispose();
      new MediaPlayerLauncher()
      {
        Media = new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative)
      }.Show();
    }
  }
}
```

changing the format to anything other than pcm works!

UPDATE: For some reason it now seems to avoid crashing but this is shown in the output:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in WP8.DLL
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in WP8.DLL and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
```

(WP8 is the name of my dll) The code carries on as normal after this and only crashes when I go to stop the recording where it says the recording never started and the AudioVideoCaptureDevice is in an incorrect state

I have also tried using var `AudioVideoCaptureDevice.SupportedAudioEncodingFormats;` to check that Pcm is available which it is

Comment: Have you tried to catch that exception to see if the exception object  provides more details?

Comment: I have, it doesn't provide any more details than what's above unfortunately!

Answer (score 1):

you can record from the mic using XNA framework (it seems to that microsoft have an error in there framework when writing data to the file!)

Take a look at this code [Microphone Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Microphone-Sample-b2ebe8b6) and this article for saving data in a wav format [Saving Microphone stream to wave format in Windows Phone](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Saving_Microphone_stream_to_wave_format_in_Windows_Phone) from Nokia developer portal!

Comment: Thanks Frederik, I have started using the XNA framework Microphone however, the bitrate and therefore the quality is not quite as good!

Comment: Yes, but can't you set higher sampleRate and bytes per sample in the code? (See WriteWavHeader from Nokia Dev. portal)

Comment: You can change the sampleRate there but if you don't put it as the same sample rate it was recorded at (160000Hz) it's going to go going really fast and I suspect will be distorted.